# how to get rid of unneeded scroll bars

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, scroll

I have a DIV that contains among other stuff a table which obviously grows or shrinks in size as rows or columns are added or deleted, when this happens the container DIV must be re-sized accordingly. If the browser's window is not big enough to show the whole table the DIV must include the necessary scroll bar(s) otherwise no scroll bars should be shown. Piece of cake, isn't it?

On IE 10 everything works just as fine as expected, however in Chrome and Safari 2 ugly scroll bars appear even when they are not necessary... at least that's what I understand when I inspect the DIV object properties and I see this:

```
this.offsetWidth = 642
this.scrollWidth = 638
```

so no horizontal scroll bar is needed, right?

```
this.offsetHeight = 420
this.scrollHeight = 416
```

so no vertical scroll bar is needed, right?

but even so, both scroll bars are shown... if I minimize the browser's window and then restore it, both scroll bars disappear, just as if the browser realized late they are not necessary. The same happens if I switch to another application and then get back to the browser, and also when I click in any off the input fields on my page. So it is obviously a bug, but haven't being able to figure out a work around.

I tried to the following:

```
this.style.overflow = "hidden";
this.style.left = q/2+"px";
this.style.width = v+"px";
this.style.top = p+"px";
this.style.height = i+"px";
this.style.overflow = "auto";
```

but I still get the same behavior.

Comment: what other styles are in play, I know a lot of boilerplate code ensure that the scrollbars are always there to avoid the site jumping when you go from a short to a long page because of the scrollbar.

Comment: did you try the overflow-y ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

It was right in font of my nose but it took time for me to realize:

```
this.style.overflow = "hidden";
this.style.left = q/2+"px";
this.style.width = v+"px";
this.style.top = p+"px";
this.style.height = i+"px";    
if(this.scrollHeight>this.offsetHeight) this.style.overflowY = "auto";
if(this.scrollWidth>this.offsetWidth) this.style.overflowX = "auto";
```